# Embedding variable text into php/html web page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to create a web page that has an area that displays different text, depending on what link was clicked.  I have looked at if else code, embedding objects, on click command.

Here is some basic code I have put together.  Can somebody let me know if I am on the right track or where I am going wrong.  I also think I need to use AJAX but I am not familiar with that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<table width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step1" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 1</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
        </td>
        <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step2" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 2</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
         </td>
         <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step3" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 3</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <br />

    <object type="text/html" width="80" height="150" border="thin">
       <?php
         if( onclick = "#Step1" ) {
            echo (i hope this work );
         } else { }
       ?>
    </object>
```

Comment: I've fixed your tags.  Java and javascript are two different things.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it just came up with the following error when I ran it:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/u531673175/public_html/Steps Page 2.php on line 102

Comment: Are you looking for the text to change when the links are clicked? If so, php by itself is not going to help you, as it is run before any of the content is sent back to the user. If you want to make changes to the page in the browser, you'll want to look at javascript.

Comment: yes... that is exactly what I am (the text to change when the link is clicked).  I had a feeling that php would not cut it, thinking it would need to be something like javascript or ajax but I am very new.  would it need to be something like an event listener? and if so, how do i go about it to do what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to have different areas show up for different links?  Here is what code would look like for that:

```
<table width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
   <tr>
<?php
switch ($_GET['step']) {
case 1:
?>
       <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step1" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 1</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
        </td>
<?php
break;
case 2:
?>
        <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step2" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 2</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
         </td>
<?php
break;
case 3:
?>
         <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step3" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 3</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
         </td>
<?php
break;
}
       </tr>
    </table>
```

This is a very simplistic way to display separate portions of markup for different urls.  You can then have your users move on to different links to show different blocks (/script.php?step=1, etc)

Comment: nah... just the one area, ideally in an object that I can put a border around.

Comment: here is a link to a site to show what i am trying to achieve

https://www.facebook.com/nrmainsurance/app_282857945119270